# Fallback mobile internet

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, internet-connection, mobile-broadband

I will be having a Linux machine (probably Ubuntu) in an environment where the wifi password changes weekly. This means that I'll have to always locally login once and change the password, before I can work with it from remote.

I'm curious whether there is a simple solution to circumvent that. Perhaps a cheap mobile connection dongle that works as a fallback and that I can use to change the wifi password?

Comment: Can you not arrange something with the Wi-Fi network's owners?

Comment: +1 for this. If they will be changing the password, can they not give it to you ahead of time maybe?

Comment: @grawity I wish that much cooperation was possible with the security department. Unfortunately, it is not: That password seems to be generated on the spot.